# Order of a permutation in $S_{7}$

Tags: finite-groups, permutations

> Question: If $\beta \in S_{7}$ and $\left | \beta^{3} \right |=7$, Prove that $\left | \beta \right |=7$.

Any permutations in $S_{n}$ for n>1 is a product of 2-cycle.

I'm lost here.

Any hints are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can be expressed as a *product* of 2-cycles is what you mean. Hint: if you express a $\beta \in S_7$ in disjoint cycle notation, what can you say about its order?

Comment: Changes made. Thanks

Comment: Say if $\beta$-(abcdefg). Expressing it as a product of disjoint cycles give six 2-cycles. The order then is LCM(2,...,2)=2.@MeesdeVries

Comment: When arguing about the _order_ of a permutation, it is usually easier to write it as a product of disjoint cycles rather than a product of $2$-cycles, since disjoint cycles commute.

Comment: But aren't products of 2-cycles themselves disjoint cycles?

Comment: @Mathematicing, if the order of $\beta$ is 2, then what is $\beta^2(a)$? Does that seem right?

Comment: Hint: What are the elements of order $7$ in $S_7$? Then consider $(\beta^3)^5=\beta^{15}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $|\beta^3|=7$ tells you that $(\beta^3)^7=\beta^{21}=e$, and that $\beta^3\neq e$. From these two facts alone, what are the possibilities for $|\beta|$? Now can you use your knowledge of $S_7$ to rule out any of the possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

For any group $G$ and $a\in G$ with $o(a) = n$,  $o(a^d) = \dfrac{n}{\gcd(n,d)}$. Here, $7 = o(\beta^3) = \dfrac{o(\beta)}{\gcd(o(\beta),3)} $ It follows that $7$ divides $o(\beta)$. Since $\beta \in S_7$, it can be written as a product of disjoint cycles. If $\beta$ is not a seven cycle, then it splits into two or more cycles of length less than 7 and hence the order of $\beta$ being the least common multiple of the lengths of the component cycles can not be a multiple of 7. Thus $\beta$ is a seven cycle and $o(\beta) = 7$.